# Create a personal VPN at home to use with specific ports

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, port

I use a network where I'm allowed to use only port 80 and 22, so I can't use many app I need, I thought about VPN and more specifically I thought of using my Raspberry Pi as VPN server (I know it creates a tunnel between host and server), the raspberry is connected at home with static IP(another network of course).

Moreover I saw that if I want add in my MacBook a VPN I have just 4 option for VPN type:

- IKEv2
- IPsec Cisco
- PPTP
- L2PT over IPsec

I listened to OpenVPN and read something, but anything about these 4

Please give me some advice, thank you.

Comment: Mac uses `Tunnel-blick` to connect to `OpenVPN` server .. is this available for your Macbook ?

Comment: just checked, yes it is available. So Can I install and set OpenVPN on my raspberry and send all packets through port 80 to raspberry with this software?

Comment: Technically, it is possible to use TCP port 80 but the Network administrator can still block non-HTTP packets.

Comment: how? if I encrypt the originale packet inside'

Comment: Because HTTP is un-encrypted and any reasonably sophisticated Firewall will be able to detect that you are not using HTTP protocol on HTTP port and so block you.  You should discuss this with your Network Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC use `Tunnelblick` with `Openvpn` -- See comments.

Comment: Comments are transient.  If you are going to move a comment to an answer, make it self-contained.  An answer that points to a comment is really just another comment.

Comment: Perhaps if the question were clear ..

Comment: The OPs question appeared to ask if `openvpn` was available for `Mac`, in the comments section i qualified that the user did not know until I asked if `Tunnelblick` was available to his distro.  He confirmed that `Tunnelblick` is available to him and so i posted this as **an** answer.  If the OP wants to clarify his question further then perhaps more detailed answer can be given.